# Zombie Error during TreasureList tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, zombie-process

I am working on an iPhone application which lists some items in a Table view. I encounter an error for the event **TreasureList tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath** while clicking on an item. I am confused over this error. The error is

`[TreasureList tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7ce0020`

Code is as under:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

ProductModel *data=[[ProductModel alloc]init];
  data=[self.treasureData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

pid=  [NSString stringWithFormat: data.ID];//WithFormat:@"%@",data.ID];
```

Please also let me know how can I debug the information "deallocated instance 0x7ce0020"

I am adding data to tableivew the following way.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
}
ProductModel *data=[self.treasureData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:data.pName];
   [data
    release];
return cell; 
}
```

Comment: How can anyone help you?  There's no code, no error info, nothing.  You need to include the relevant code.

Comment: Add the code for your implementation of didSelectRowAtIndexPath plus any properties, objects, functions that it interacts with

Comment: Sorry, I have made the code available

Comment: Is that anything to do with the custom cell?

Comment: ProductModel *data=[[ProductModel alloc]init];
  data=[self.treasureData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
These two lines makes no sense :-P, you do not need to allocate the 'data' as you are using it from your array, I am sure this 'data' is being released and you are using it later somewhere, what property type have you used for  'treasureData'

Comment: How is treasureData defined in .h and how is it created.  I wonder if it's deallocated by then.  Also, if you set a break point in that method what line does it blow up on?

Comment: You do not need to release your data object, if your have not put an extra retain/copy somewhere while adding these ProductModel objects to your array.

Comment: It is defined in .h file as @property (atomic,retain) NSMutableArray *treasureData;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gijo You might get this error due to some already message being sent to already released Object which you are either using in your table cell , or When you are trying to use something in the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method, which has already being released viz some object, label etc.

Comment: Is that anything to do with a custom cell?

Comment: Yes pretty much possible, please put some code and update your question accordingly. A code is always appreciated while asking anything related to crash or otherwise :-)

Comment: I've modified my original question with the code I used to populate Tableview.

Comment: I finally resolved the issue by releasing some objects. Thanks for the help.